# Insert struct in two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

When I try to add struct in two-dimensional array

```
cin>>array[1][items.stoka_ime];
```

in error list write this:

```
    IntelliSense: no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From your question its not clear what is your actual problem. So i just show a sample of array and structure combined usage.

For arrays of structures

```
struct abc
{
int i;
int j;
}

abc object[10];

cin>>object[0].i>>object[0].j;
```

Arrays in structures

```
struct abc
    {
      int i[10];
    }         
 abc object;                  
 cin>>object.i[0];
```

For pushing into queue array of structures:

```
queue.push(array[i]);
```

Comment: That's nice, but how does it relate to the question?

Comment: its possible of inter mixing of arrays and structures in a not proper way

Comment: Ok but how to push object in queue ?

Comment: @NikolaiCekov please rephrase the question with relevant code.

Comment: push object? Queue? Sorry i dint see all that mentioned in the question

Comment: Ok, cin>>items[i].test, cin>>items[i].price and when I try q.push(items); have error

Comment: You have to use `q.push(items[i]);`

Comment: Cant push the whole array together have to use a loop and insert one element at time into the `queue`

Comment: @ Luchian Grigore: Thus the problem is solved! Mind taking off the down vote?

Comment: Okay sorry thought it was you!!

Comment: Not to say I don't understand why it's downvoted. Of course, for such a question, a sensible answer is impossible. Instead of urging the OP to rephrase the question, so that it's actually helpful to others in the future, you condone & promote this style of asking questions. So although I didn't downvote, know that I would have if I didn't have a round number as rep.

Comment: i'm not promoting this type of questions. I was just trying to analyse his problem. Asking him to post more code and down voting a question doesnt always help